# Center of chart(pieChart)

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts, typescript

I want to set title of pieChart in the middle of circle like this http://jsfiddle.net/NVX3S/1036/ .

```
 title: {
        text: 'aSD<br>500 ASD.',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',

    }
```

But: title.align is the option of the svg container, not the chart align!
(Imagine what will happen if left of chart will be legend of chart -- title of the chart will not place in the middle of the chart)

I was looking for solution this problem, but found only this: http://jsfiddle.net/NVX3S/2/

```
var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth  * 0.5);
    var textY = chart.plotTop  + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5);

    var span = '<span id="pieChartInfoText" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;">';
    span += '<span style="font-size: 32px">Upper</span><br>';
    span += '<span style="font-size: 16px">Lower</span>';
    span += '</span>';

    $("#addText").append(span);
    span = $('#pieChartInfoText');
    span.css('left', textX + (span.width() * -0.5));
    span.css('top', textY + (span.height() * -0.5));
```

Instead of the title using span element with text, which centered through the:

chart.plotLeft, chart.plotTop, chart.plotWidth, chart.plotHeight which I can't get, because using TypeScript abstraction.

Does anyone have any ideas how to center title(or text) in the pieChart(chart)??? Thanks.

Comment: Nice question! Here is a clear example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/NVX3S/1037/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pie center can be calculated using pie series center array (x and y coordinates), plotLeft and plotTop.
Using renderer.text it is possible to add text.
In redraw event additionally rendered text should be adjusted to stay in the center of pie.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/1917s4pL/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie',
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    var chart = this,
                        x = chart.plotLeft + (chart.series[0].center[0]),
                        y = chart.plotTop + (chart.series[0].center[1]),
                        box;

                    chart.pieCenter = chart.renderer.text('aSD<br>500 ASD.', x, y, true)
                        .css({
                        'text-align': 'center',
                        color: 'black',
                        fontSize: '16px'
                    })
                        .add();

                    box = chart.pieCenter.getBBox();
                    chart.pieCenter.attr({
                        x: x - box.width / 2,
                        y: y - box.height / 4
                    });
                },
                redraw: function () {
                    var chart = this,
                        x = chart.plotLeft + (chart.series[0].center[0]),
                        y = chart.plotTop + (chart.series[0].center[1]),
                        box = chart.pieCenter.getBBox();
                    chart.pieCenter.attr({
                        x: x - box.width / 2,
                        y: y - box.height / 4
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: '40%'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        series: [{
            showInLegend: true,
            data: [
                ['Firefox', 44.2],
                ['IE7', 26.6],
                ['IE6', 20],
                ['Chrome', 3.1],
                ['Other', 5.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```